# Rails - Access to routes from seedfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I want to seed a single Page, that has many files and now I do it like this:

```
PageFile.create!([
  { file_body: seedfile('/file1.jpg'), page_id: Page.where(path: 'my_page').take.id }
```

But I think it's not flexible and I want it to depend on by routes.rb data:

```
get 'my_page' => 'pages#my_page', as: :my_page
```

I tried:

```
page_id: Page.where(path: my_page_path) }
page_id: Page.where(path: :my_page_path) }
page_id: Page.where(path: Page.select(:my_page_path)) }
```

All of them return errors or nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use url helpers with :

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_page_path
```

For url:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_page_url
```

Note: url will add default host, to change host, you will need to add following in `application.rb`: 
`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "mysite.com"`

To access it across rake, you can `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in file and access `my_page_path` normally.